# Xcode Core Data: Change existing XML to Sqlite (NSXMLStoreType to NSSQLiteStoreType)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, sqlite, core-data-migration

On my first app I used within my persistant store coordinater a NSXMLStoreType.

```
[storeCooordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSXMLStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:nil];
```

Now, I like to change to a NSSQLiteStoreType:

```
[storeCooordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:nil];
```

The app crashes, if I simply change the store type. So what I have to do? May I have to do once:

- check if the old store exists and
- if yes convert it to sqlite and
- delete afterwards the old xml store?

I have no idea how to convert it to sqlite. The models are the same.

> **EDIT & ANSWER**

I use this solution to migrate once the database (**thanks to Volker**)

```
//-> applicationFilesDirectory is the url to the documents directory

NSURL* oldURL = [applicationFilesDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DBName1.xml"];
NSURL* newURL = [applicationFilesDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DBName2.sqlite"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        //-> if file exists            
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[oldURL path]]) {
            NSLog(@"File is here");

            NSManagedObjectModel* managedModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
            NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* tempCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedModel];

            id xmlStore =  [tempCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSXMLStoreType configuration:nil URL:oldURL options:options error:nil];

            [tempCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:newURL options:options error:nil];

            if ( ![tempCoordinator migratePersistentStore:xmlStore toURL:newURL options:options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error] ) {
                //-> delete the old file from directory
                [fileManager removeItemAtURL:oldURL error:NULL];
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think your `if ( ![tempCoordinator migratePersistentStore` test is the wrong way around. When migration fails to create the new store, that's when you delete the old store. I would imagine if you are unable to create the new store, you don't want to delete the old store (unless it's throwaway data).

Comment: Also, your call to `addPersistentStoreWithType:` is unnecessary. `migratePersistentStore:` migrates to a new store that does not need to be listed in the store types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` as described in [Apples Core Data documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingPersistentStores.html).

If this should happen automatically, you will need to add the migration at startup.