# Core Data Migration: Changing Persistent Store ofType

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data, cloudkit

I really need help to change Core Data structure. I have built my app already with existing database but now I would like to use Seam cloudKit sync and I have to change my code but if I do that my app will crash!
(delete and build the app again is not an option.. as I mention it has already its data structure)

In `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` I used the following code:

```
try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
```

Now I have to use that:

```
try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: SMStore.type, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]) as? SMStore
```

As you noticed I have to change the ofType from `NSSQLiteStoreType` to `SMStore.type`

Is there any way to do that? Is anyone has any idea? I hope someone could help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` method `migratePersistentStore(_:to:options:withType:)` for this. This method moves an existing persistent store file to a new file, and can change the persistent store type. Even though it has "migrate" in the name, it doesn't have anything to do with model version migration. In this case it migrates the persistent store to a new file.

You'll have to add the persistent store using the old store type and then migrate to the new store type.

Comment: I did it.. But it always run Error... I tried that:
[link](https://github.com/kevinzhow/Diary/blob/master/Diary/Helper/DiaryCoreData.swift)
or that:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566819/xcode-core-data-change-existing-xml-to-sqlite-nsxmlstoretype-to-nssqlitestoret)
I always got an error... the try never run..

Comment: Saying that you got an error **without saying what the error was** is **always** a waste of time. What error did you get?

Comment: This error is based on the second link:
2017-01-18 19:15:59.901216 Seam3_Example[72047:3429091] [error] error: Illegal attempt to save to a file that was never opened. "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation.". No last error recorded.
2017-01-18 19:15:59.926 Seam3_Example[72047:3429091] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation.'

Comment: This error I got is based on the first link.. (here I run the migration from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)"

Comment: Your first error message suggests that you attempted to do the migration *before* adding the old persistent store instead of after adding it.

Comment: Thatswhy I call the migration after that.. than I got the error 1570. Or other numbers but message "The operation couldn't be completed" is always the same

Comment: Then there are other problems with your code that need more detail to explain. The `migratePersistentStore` call is how you do what you described in the question.