# persistentStoreForURL always returns nil

Tags: macos, sqlite, core-data-migration

I am attempting to migrate my Core Data store from XML to SQLite. I created a URL to the old XML data store (I verified the path), then created a URL to where the new SQLite data store should go. When I call persistentStoreForURL (from the persistent store coordinator class), passing in the URL to the XML data store, it returns nil. I'm not sure why this is. I've done multiple Google searches and found some people having the same issue, but no resolution.

```
- (nullable NSPersistentStore *)migrateXMLStoreAtURL:(nonnull NSURL *)XMLStoreURL toSQLiteStoreAtURL:(nonnull NSURL *)SQLiteStoreURL
{
    NSParameterAssert(XMLStoreURL != nil);
    NSParameterAssert(SQLiteStoreURL != nil);


    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *XMLStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:XMLStoreURL];
    NSPersistentStore *SQLiteStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:XMLStore toURL:SQLiteStoreURL
                                    options:nil withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

    if (SQLiteStore == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to migrate XML data store to SQLite data store.\n%@", [error description]);
    }

    return SQLiteStore;
}
```

XMLStore is always returning nil, even though the URL does point to an existing file.

Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, did you find the cause?

Thanks!

Comment: See [Xcode Core Data: Change existing XML to Sqlite (NSXMLStoreType to NSSQLiteStoreType)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566819/xcode-core-data-change-existing-xml-to-sqlite-nsxmlstoretype-to-nssqlitestoret)

Comment: I've seen that post before. This seems to be a different problem.

Comment: You have added the XML store to the coordinator before calling this method?

Comment: Thanks Warren! That pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that resolved my issue. I removed some code from the persistentStoreCoordinator method in this example for brevity.

```
- (nullable NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator)
    {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }


    NSURL *newSQLiteDataStoreURL = [coreDataStoreDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewCoreDataStore.sqldata"];
    NSURL *oldXMLDataStoreURL = [coreDataStoreDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"OldCoreDataStore.storedata"];
    BOOL oldXMLDataStoreExists = [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:oldXMLDataStoreURL.path];

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSString *persistentStoreType = oldXMLDataStoreExists ? NSXMLStoreType : NSSQLiteStoreType;
    NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @(YES)};
    NSURL *dataStoreURL = oldXMLDataStoreExists ? oldXMLDataStoreURL : SQLiteDataStoreURL;

    NSPersistentStore persistentStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:persistentStoreType configuration:nil URL:dataStoreURL options:options error:&error];

    if (persistentStore == nil)
    {
        // Handle error.
    }


    // Check if the old XML data store is present. If so, migrate to a SQLite data store.

    if (oldXMLDataStoreExists)
    {
        // The old XML data store is present. Migrate to a SQLite data store.

        NSPersistentStore *migratedPersistentStore = [self migrateXMLPersistentStore:persistentStore toSQLiteStoreAtURL:SQLiteDataStoreURL];

        if (migratedPersistentStore == nil)
        {
            [self presentCoreDataError:error failureReason:failureReason];
        }
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

    return coordinator;
}



- (nullable NSPersistentStore *)migrateXMLPersistentStore:(nonnull NSPersistentStore *)XMLStore toSQLiteStoreAtURL:(nonnull NSURL *)SQLiteStoreURL
{
    NSParameterAssert(XMLStore != nil);
    NSParameterAssert(SQLiteStoreURL != nil);


    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *SQLiteStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:XMLStore toURL:SQLiteStoreURL options:nil withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

    if (SQLiteStore == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to migrate XML data store to SQLite data store.\n%@", [error description]);
    }
    else
    {
        // Remove the old XML store.
    }

    return SQLiteStore;
}
```